# What differences are between javascript in Firefox 4 and IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, ecma262, firefox4

IE9 supports ecma-262 edition 5 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) and Firefox 4 is javascript 1.8.5 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8.5).

How compliant is IE9 with ECMA-262 edition 5 and is that the same as ECMAScript5?

I expect there are more differences than similarities between the two javascript engines, but I am curious how close IE9 has moves toward Firefox, in terms of new javascript functionality.

Comment: Yes, ECMA-262 Edition 5 is the same as ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Read about IE9 support for EcmaScript 5 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more.aspx

Comment: Also here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/27/ecmascript-5-part-1-reusable-code.aspx and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/12/13/ecmascript-5-part-2-array-extras.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE 9 pretty much supports ECMAScript 5, except for the Strict Mode.

ECMAScript 5 support in browsers compared by [@kangax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/ (*note that the table shows only existence, not functionality*)

Definitely there'll differences between the JavaScript Engines - Chakra, SpiderMonkey, V8 and others, as the implementations will vary and their support for non-standard features http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/non-standard/

Comment: I never saw the site you suggested, it looks very helpful.